# dlib static lib error in debug mode

Tags: c++, debugging, dlib

I'm currently trying dlib **19.1** for a project.

I build all the example using cmake, and I also build dlib with VS 2013 to obtain the static lib. So I have my Install folder where the dlib are created. I compile in Release and also in Debug using the same .sln created with the cmake. So until now, no problem.

Next to that, I went in my project (a console project), and I pointed to header and lib (release and debug). Note that this project only contain a Main.cpp that call different function from my own other project libs and that main also call the face landmarks detection from dlib.

So, I have no issue to compile my project in Release with the dlib.lib that I created. But when using the **debug dlib.lib** and try to launch my own project in debug mode, I obtain the following error :

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_

Is there anything done wrong ? When I'm looking to my preprocessor in cmake .sln in debug I have the _DEBUG and also in my own project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution is to build dlib not from .sln files, but directly by cmake:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\prj\dlib_build_release
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\prj\dlib_build_debug
cmake --build . --target install --config Debug
```

This will compile and install dlib binaries and headers into c:\prj\dlib_build_release and c:\prj\dlib_build_debug directories
After that you can use dlib compiled library from this directories

Comment: The idea was good to give a try. I just finish that, and same result. The project still outputing the same error.

Comment: I noticed that my ENABLE_ASSERTS was not selected by default (as said here : http://dlib.net/compile.html. But the problem was just to activate this for the debug build. I noticed it by checking all parameters in the GUI directly. **Note** that Im using dlib 19.1 instead of 19.4, which might have difference between documentation (I don't know).

Comment: any other errors? may be library is not linked because x64/x86 incompatibility?

Comment: Problem solve now. The issue is that I was configuring directly via the console (cmake ..) and never used the GUI. So I took for granted that the default config was good. But its look like when I opened with cmake GUI, that the ENABLE_ASSERT was not check, so I had to mark it and I also follow your advice and directly via cmake instead of opening the .sln generated. So I have a working solution for debug and release now.

Comment: Thanks. I had the exact same problem and your solution worked like a charm.